# Remove particular char from end of a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have few records like this in one table

```
            123456/
            53787899/
            68239003-21/
            5761289903120,7278/
            574738992842/478389
```

I would like to check if `/` (slash) exists at end of the string, and if so, remove the slash from the end only.

I have an idea that using `charindex` or `partindex` will work.

But, how to use this?

I would like my output string to be

```
            123456
            53787899
            68239003-21
            5761289903120,7278
            574738992842/478389
```

Note: there can be spaces after the `/` (slash). Please let me know to do this.

DDL

```
declare @t table (MyString VARCHAR(40) NULL)

insert @t (MyString)
values ('123456/'), ('53787899/'), ('68239003-21/'),
       ('5761289903120,7278/'), ('574738992842/478389')

select * 
from @t
```

Comment: If there are spaces after the slash, do you want to remove the slash?

Comment: I just want to remove slash. There should not be any keyboard chars after that except space.If any space, i will assume that there is nothing after slash, hence i'll remove slash.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RIGHT` with number of character to match to find if the string ends with `'/'` character.

```
  DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)='5761289903120,7278/'
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(@STR,1)='/' THEN SUBSTRING(@STR, 1, (LEN(@STR) - 1)) ELSE @STR END
```

**Working Example**

```
    WITH MT AS
    (
     SELECT * FROM
     (VALUES('123456/'),('53787899/'),('68239003-21/'),('5761289903120,7278/'),('574738992842/478389')) T(mystring)
    )

   SELECT 
      CASE WHEN RIGHT(mystring,1)='/' THEN SUBSTRING(mystring, 1, (LEN(mystring) - 1)) ELSE mystring END
   FROM MT
```

**Output**

```
    MyString
   ---------
    123456
    53787899
    68239003-21
    5761289903120,7278
    574738992842/478389
```

Edit: If you want to eliminate any spaces in the last you can change the query like following.

```
RIGHT(RTRIM(mystring),1)='/'
```

Using in Where clause

```
 SELECT  CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(MY_COLUMN),1)='/' THEN SUBSTRING(MY_COLUMN, 1, (LEN(MY_COLUMN) - 1)) ELSE MY_COLUMN END AS MY_COLUMN
 FROM [MY_TABLE]
 WHERE RTRIM(MY_COLUMN) LIKE '%/'
```

If you want to update it back to the table, you can use query like following.

```
 UPDATE T
 SET T.MY_COLUMN = CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(MY_COLUMN),1)='/' THEN SUBSTRING(MY_COLUMN, 1, (LEN(MY_COLUMN) - 1)) ELSE MY_COLUMN END
 FROM [MY_TABLE] T
```

Comment: Its a database table, I find need to find the records (using where condition) where there are only "slash at the end" and then replace the slash.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
declare @t table (
    MyString VARCHAR(40) NULL
)

insert @t (MyString)
VALUES ('123456/'),
    ('53787899/'),
    ('68239003-21/'),
    ('5761289903120,7278/'),
    ('574738992842/478389')

select  MyString,
        CASE WHEN MyString LIKE '%/' THEN LEFT(MyString, LEN(MyString)-1) ELSE MyString END NewValue
from    @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
declare @T table (string varchar(100));
insert into @T values 
       (' 123456/')
      , (' 53787899/')
      , ('68239003-21/')
      , ('5761289903120,7278/')
      , ('5761289903120,7279/ ')
      , ('574738992842/478389 ')
      , ('574738992842/478390 ');
select '''' + t.string + '''' from @T t;
update t 
set t.string = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.string)), 1, LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(T.string))) - 1)
from @T t
where t.string like '%/';
select t.string from @T t;
```